# silverlight datafrom commit button does not get enabled first time on typing in the input box

Tags: silverlight

when the Silverlight dataform's property autogeneratedfields is set to true everything works fine (the button behavior is correct, meaning as soon as  I start typing it gets enabled. So, now i have a scenario where i had to customize the look of the dataform and set autogeneratefields to false ( i am manually using datafields in xaml) , when i type in something in a textbox, the commit button is not enabled, it only gets enabled when i put the mouse in the next textbox. Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your object an `IEditableObject` (System.ComponentModel).

What's cool about the `DataForm` is that it tries to communicate with the object with the current state of what's going on.  If `AutoGenerateFields` is being used, then there is something that is between the templating engine of the dataform and the object it is trying to use, thus making completing the loop for you.

If there isn't an interface (because you provided the template, yourself) to an `IEditableObject` available, the `DataForm` doesn't know it is actually editing an object until a Binding is updated.  In Silverlight, Bindings are updated only AFTER the a `TextBox` has lost focus.

The point of an IEditableObject is to tell objects that this guy knows how to Cancel and Save appropriately.  This is especially important when the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) tells us we need to be able to rollback the object to its original state.  So when you begin your edit, you can keep a copy of it around.  Then, when cancel is clicked, you will be able to rollback your changes by copying the data back.  I'd check out the MSDN article, they do a good job explaining it.

If you make your objects an `IEditableObject`, then this behavior may return to the way you want.  If not, then I do not understand the problem correctly and would love to see the code for a small sample.

Also, feel free to check out the source code for the `DataForm` on CodePlex: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71382

I've had to browse the code many times to figure something out.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi, I got a class called CustomerSearch which the datafrom is bound to, so what do i put inside the BeginEdit? Every property in the CustomerSearch class has a RaisePropertyChanged("") method in the setter.

Comment: I got the viewmodel to implement the IEditableObject interface instead but having a problem with ElementName on the xaml part throw designer error Binding_SourceConflict: CurrentItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, ElementName=MemberSearch, Path=Main.MemberSearch,Mode=TwoWay}"